# wrong index in document selection, while selected text is have a dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting text, which selected from html page by the user. I am printing this text's index in an array.

I am having a paragraph of text contents. There is no problem in getting index of selected text, while selecting text without dot(.),

But when selecting texts with dot(.) index value is always showing 1.

for example, in below paragraph

```
    I am working in HTML with jquery. I want to make a webpage to highlight some text lines (line nos 15, 22, 32) in that page at a time. This can be done by left click in mouse and drag that line, so that the text line is selected with blue background.
```

While I am selecting "working in html" this looks good in array and index is prints as '5'.

But when I am selecting "jquery. I want to" (having dot). index is not available as it is(26).

Here is my code, https://jsfiddle.net/qL659gmh/7/

```
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="test">I am working in HTML with jquery.
      I want to make a webpage to highlight some text lines (line nos 15, 22, 32) in that page at a time. This can be done by left click in mouse and drag that line, so that the text line is selected with blue background.
    I am able to get the selected lines as follows using jquery,
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">     
    var arr = [];

    $('#test').mouseup(function () {
        var output='';
        output += getSelectedText();
        arr.push(output);
        highlightSelected();
        $('#result').html(output);
        indx(output);

    });

    function getSelectedText() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            return window.getSelection().toString();
        } else if (document.selection) {
            return document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        return '';
    }

    function indx(text){
        inputText = document.getElementById("test")
        var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML
        var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
        console.log("innerHTML---------------"+innerHTML)
        console.log("text---------------"+text)
        console.log("index---------------"+index)

    }
```

Comment: It's working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/qL659gmh/

Comment: Which browser are you using? It is working fine on chrome,mozilla and ie

Comment: @ketan, Updated my question. Pls take a look, now I explained my issue as good.

Comment: @amitguptageek, Updated my question. Pls take a look, now I explained my issue as good.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `innerText` instead of `innerHtml` because `document.selection.createRange().text` return plain text without any markups, that is placed on line break after dot(.). To be more clear the problem is not the dot(.), but new line after dot(.), that is not displayed by browser
Here's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qL659gmh/8/)

Comment: This is ok, but I am having a button to highlight the selected text, After using innerText instead of innerHtml, it highlights all the text after that index.

Comment: can you provide your highlighting function?